# React-Native Background Tasks - repeat less then 15 Minutes?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, background

The following question: In React-Native via the library react-native-background-fetch it is possible to execute a task in the background. For example to send a push notification. I looked at the following example in the course: https://medium.com/@alihaghani/background-tasks-and-local-push-notifications-with-react-native-d63fc7fff9b

Now in the documentation of "react-native-background-fetch" it is written that it is not possible to run a task under 15 minutes interval. Does anyone know how I can still run a task for example every minute or every 2 minutes?

If not, does anyone have a solution for the following problem:
(minimal example) I have an app that searches for Bluetooth connections in your area. When a signal is found, then show a push notification. Every minute it searches for a signal. This should happen in the background of course. For this it should be checked under 15 minutes.
Is this somehow possible with react-native?

I have already built an app that displays push notifications. I have implemented this with Firebase. In my opinion, Firebase will not be able to help me here, because the push notification is only sent when a certain logic applies, right?

Thanks to anyone who can give me some thought or even a solution to the problem